# Problem making hyperref work in conjunction with biber

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, biber

Here is my minimal working example. I have a .bib file given by

```
@article{example,
    author  =   {Author},
    title   =   {Title},
    journal =   {Journal},
    year    =   {2018},
    url     =   {\href{https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.08794}{arXiv:1606.08794}}
}
```

and a .tex file

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{} % cosmetical

\begin{document}
    I want to cite \cite{example}.

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The outputted bibliography has the single entry

> [Aut18] Author, "Title". *Journal* (2018). URL: %5Cref%7Bhttps://arxiv.org/abs/1606.08794%7D%7BarXiv:1606.08794%7D

Instead of the desired

> [Aut18] Author, "Title". *Journal* (2018). URL: [arXiv:1606.08794](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.08794)

I see what happens, and I understand more or less what the problem is, but I don't know how to solve it. Does anyone know how to make it work?

Note 1: If I just put `url = {https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.08794}`, then I get the full url as a hyperlink in the bibliography, but I would really like it to be in shortened form.

Note 2: I took one random article in my bibliography for the link.

Comment: arXiv preprints are given in the `eprint` field: `eprint = {1606.08794}, eprinttype = {arxiv}` (maybe also `eprintclass = {math.AT}`). The URL field is always read verbatim and must be fed a URL, no markup is allowed. If you don't want to see the URL as entered in the URL field you must use a different field.

Comment: @moewe Ok, thanks. If you put your comment as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: How would you answer the question if it was not a defined format like arxiv? I think the problem with \DeclareFieldFormat is that it can only take one variable. So if I try \DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\href{#1}{#2}} and then url = {\href{https://google.com}{MyTxt}} It fails... Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `url` field is read verbatim and must always be a bare URL only. You don't need to escape any special characters and you cannot use any markup commands.

If you wish for a different format of the URL field, you must modify the field format via `\DeclareFieldFormat`. This is not necessary here, since `biblatex` has a native way of dealing with arXiv preprints. You can use `eprint`

```
eprint      = {1606.08794},
eprinttype  = {arxiv},
```

maybe also

```
eprintclass = {math.AT},
```